# Move forward view while wheel click

Tags: 3d-view, workflow

It'd be awesome to use the arrows to move the camera reference point with wasdqe, just like in walk mode, as soon as the wheel click is pressed (in addition to rotation (or translation if shift is pressed))

Is there a way to do that ?

Thanks

Comment: can you enable "Lock Camera to View" in the properties panel, and then use walk mode?

Comment: I couldn't find "Lock Camera to View" button either in Blender or in the doc, which property panel are you refering to ? Thanks

Comment: ok i made and answer that shows you where it is.

Answer (score 0):

Open the properties panel in the viewport by pressing N. Then, under the "View" tab of the panel, check "Lock Camera to View".

[image: properties]

Go into camera view mode, and then move around the viewport however you want (e.g. in walk mode) and the camera will follow.

Comment: Thanks, sorry, what I meant wasn't very clear: I want to move the view, not the camera.
So what I want is to use the "rotate view", and while keeping the button pressing being able to move it thanks to the qweasd keys, just like in walk mode. The difference with walk mode is that instead of having the rotation point being the point of the view, it would be somewhere in from of it (just like when you're using the rotation view). The second difference is that there's no need to confirm the new view (as in walk mode), the new view is confirmed when the button is released.